# Web scraping links for Long and Lat Values

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrap a link that contains the value of longitude and latitude, but unfortunately, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

Latitude=[]
Longitude=[]

url='http://www.geonames.org/5549030'
r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

longitude_findall = soup.find_all ('div', attrs= {'class': 'tab-content'})
for item in info:
latitude= item.find('span',{'title':'latitude'})
print(latitude)
```

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTnTD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website is loading the information dynamically. In such cases, you want to open the Dev Tools and look up Network tab, to see which calls are made.  You are likely to see another url being accessed for some JSON data, like in this case.

The following code works, and is returning what you need (and much more info, just inspect the json response):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

Latitude=[]
Longitude=[]

url='http://www.geonames.org/getJSON?id=5549030'
r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.json()['lat'])
```

Result:

```
39.25024
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @platipus_on_fire_333. I Have a column with a 10000 link, is it possible to loop this code to get all the Lat and Long values and add them to new columns?

Comment: Yes it is. Post a new question with a sample of that list of links.